# matplotlib.pyplot custom legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a rather crowded legend. I would like to make it lighter. Let the following mock data:

```
import pandas as pd

Compact = pd.DataFrame(data=[['E',1,-20,0.02],
                             ['E',2,-21,0.025],
                             ['S',1,-19,0.015],
                             ['S',2,-19.3,0.012],
                             ['S0',1,-21.2,0.023],
                             ['S0',2,-20.7,0.013],
                             ['S0a',1,-21.5,0.017],
                             ['S0a',2,-20.1,0.026]
                            ],columns=['Morph','rank','R','z'])
Compact_left = pd.DataFrame(data=[['E',1,-19.8,0.023],
                                  ['E',2,-21.5,0.018],
                                  ['S',1,-18.9,0.015],
                                  ['S',2,-19.2,0.009],
                                  ['S0',1,-17.9,0.011],
                                  ['S0',2,-20.5,0.007],
                                  ['S0a',1,-17.8,0.008],
                                  ['S0a',2,-20.5,0.006]
                                 ],columns=['Morph','rank','R','z'])
```

I plot my data using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='S') & (Compact['rank'] == 1)]['z'],
            Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='S') & (Compact['rank'] == 1)]['R'],  
            c='b', marker='^', 
            label = "$S$, central, selected")
plt.scatter(Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='S') & (Compact['rank'] > 1)]['z'],
            Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='S') & (Compact['rank'] > 1)]['R'],  
            c='b', marker='o', 
            label = "$S$, satellite, selected")
plt.scatter(Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='S') & (Compact_left['rank'] == 1)]['z'],
            Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='S') & (Compact_left['rank'] == 1)]['R'],  
            facecolors='none', edgecolors='b', marker='^', 
            label = "$S$, central, put aside")
plt.scatter(Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='S') & (Compact_left['rank'] > 1)]['z'],
            Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='S') & (Compact_left['rank'] > 1)]['R'],  
            facecolors='none', edgecolors='b', marker='o', 
            label = "$S$, satellite, put aside")

plt.scatter(Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='S0') & (Compact['rank'] == 1)]['z'],
            Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='S0') & (Compact['rank'] == 1)]['R'],  
            c='g', marker='^', 
            label = "$S0$, central, selected")
plt.scatter(Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='S0') & (Compact['rank'] > 1)]['z'],
            Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='S0') & (Compact['rank'] > 1)]['R'],  
            c='g', marker='o', 
            label = "$S0$, satellite, selected")
plt.scatter(Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='S0') & (Compact_left['rank'] == 1)]['z'],
            Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='S0') & (Compact_left['rank'] == 1)]['R'],  
            facecolors='none', edgecolors='g', marker='^',
            label = "$S0$, central, put aside")
plt.scatter(Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='S0') & (Compact_left['rank'] > 1)]['z'],
            Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='S0') & (Compact_left['rank'] > 1)]['R'],  
            facecolors='none', edgecolors='g', marker='o',
            label = "$S0$, satellite, put aside")

plt.scatter(Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='E') & (Compact['rank'] == 1)]['z'],
            Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='E') & (Compact['rank'] == 1)]['R'],  
            c='r', marker='^',
            label = "$E$, central, selected")            
plt.scatter(Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='E') & (Compact['rank'] > 1)]['z'],
            Compact.loc[(Compact['Morph']=='E') & (Compact['rank'] > 1)]['R'],  
            c='r', marker='o', 
            label = "$E$, satellite, selected")
plt.scatter(Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='E') & (Compact_left['rank'] == 1)]['z'],
            Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='E') & (Compact_left['rank'] == 1)]['R'],  
            facecolors='none', edgecolors='r', marker='^',
            label = "$E$, central, put aside")            
plt.scatter(Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='E') & (Compact_left['rank'] > 1)]['z'],
            Compact_left.loc[(Compact_left['Morph']=='E') & (Compact_left['rank'] > 1)]['R'],  
            facecolors='none', edgecolors='r', marker='o',
            label = "$E$, satellite, put aside")

plt.scatter(Compact.loc[(~Compact['Morph'].isin(['S','E','S0'])) & (Compact['rank'] == 1)]['z'],
            Compact.loc[(~Compact['Morph'].isin(['S','E','S0'])) & (Compact['rank'] == 1)]['R'],  
            c='y', marker='^',
            label = "Other, central, selected")                        
plt.scatter(Compact.loc[(~Compact['Morph'].isin(['S','E','S0'])) & (Compact['rank'] > 1)]['z'],
            Compact.loc[(~Compact['Morph'].isin(['S','E','S0'])) & (Compact['rank'] > 1)]['R'],  
            c='y', marker='o',
            label = "Other, satellite, selected")
plt.scatter(Compact_left.loc[(~Compact_left['Morph'].isin(['S','E','S0'])) & (Compact_left['rank'] == 1)]['z'],
            Compact_left.loc[(~Compact_left['Morph'].isin(['S','E','S0'])) & (Compact_left['rank'] == 1)]['R'],  
            facecolors='none', edgecolors='y', marker='^',
            label = "Other, central, put aside")            
plt.scatter(Compact_left.loc[(~Compact_left['Morph'].isin(['S','E','S0'])) & (Compact_left['rank'] > 1)]['z'],
            Compact_left.loc[(~Compact_left['Morph'].isin(['S','E','S0'])) & (Compact_left['rank'] > 1)]['R'],  
            facecolors='none', edgecolors='y', marker='o',
            label = "Other, satellite, put aside")


axes = plt.gca()
zinf, zsup = Compact_raw['z'].min(),Compact_raw['z'].max()
zrange = zsup - zinf
z1, z2 = zinf - 0.03*zrange, zsup + 0.03*zrange
Rinf, Rsup = [Compact_raw['R'].min(),Compact_raw['R'].max()]
Rrange = Rsup - Rinf 
R1, R2 = Rinf - 0.03*Rrange, Rsup + 0.03*Rrange
axes.set_xlim(z1, z2)
axes.set_ylim(R1, R2)
axes.invert_yaxis()

leg = plt.legend(frameon=True, loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.33, 0.5))

leg.get_frame().set_edgecolor('k')
plt.xlabel('$z$', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('$M_r$', fontsize=20)

plt.axvline(0.01, color='c', linestyle='dashed', linewidth = 1)
plt.axhline(R_min, color='c', linestyle='dashed', linewidth = 1);
```

With my own data, the result is the following:
[image]

As you can see, the legend is too complicated. I would like to build a custom legend to explain that:

- Blue is for S, red for E, green for S0 and yellow for the others
- Triangles are for central galaxies and round for satellites
- Full markers are selected galaxies and empty ones are left aside

Using an old language, I was able to do something like the following:
[image]

This was not very beautiful, but in terms of legend, a bit more efficient. I've tried various strategies, but I'm unable to make Pyplot do something clean. How should I do?

Comment: Did you read the [Legend Guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html)? I guess the best would be to use proxy artists to create your legend.

Comment: I suppose you're right. I'll see if I'm able to do exactly what I want from there. Thank you for your advice.